# Using sql with in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, where-clause, with-clause

How can i use with in a query like this? Is there a way to use the tableIds in TableList? Can i treat them like a subquery?

```
select * from TestTable where tableId in 

(WITH TableList (tableId)
AS
(
SELECT tableId FROM OldTable WHERE tableId=5 and IsDeleted = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT t.tableId From OldTable as t
INNER JOIN TableList as p
ON t.ParenTableId = p.TableId
WHERE t.IsDeleted = 0
)
SELECT tableId FROM TableList
)
```

EDIT: To show why i cant use with in first statement of sql.

```
select TableId, IsDeleted,
( 
  select count(OtherId) OtherTable
  where otherTableId in 
  (WITH TableList (tableId)
  AS
  (
  SELECT tableId FROM OldTable WHERE tableId=5 and IsDeleted = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.tableId From OldTable as t
  INNER JOIN TableList as p
  ON t.ParenTableId = p.TableId
  WHERE t.IsDeleted = 0
  )
  SELECT tableId FROM TableList
  )
  ) as Ex1
from TestTable where tableId in (1,2,3)
```

I think this show why im trying to use with clause in the middle of a sql query.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: im trying to get tables recursive. In my OldTable columns are like TableId, ParentTableId and Isdeleted. By using this sql im trying to get all the child tables of tableId = 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your WITH CTE before calling the SQL:

```
WITH TableList (tableId)
AS
(
    SELECT tableId FROM OldTable WHERE tableId=5 and IsDeleted = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.tableId From OldTable as t
        INNER JOIN TableList as p
            ON t.ParenTableId = p.TableId
    WHERE t.IsDeleted = 0
)
SELECT * 
FROM TestTable 
WHERE tableId in 
(
    SELECT tableId FROM TableList
)
```

*EDIT -- Based on your comments, you could define your Recursive CTE in a VIEW and then use as needed:*

```
CREATE VIEW YourView AS 
WITH TableList (tableId)
AS
(
    SELECT tableId FROM OldTable WHERE tableId=5 and IsDeleted = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.tableId From OldTable as t
        INNER JOIN TableList as p
            ON t.ParenTableId = p.TableId
    WHERE t.IsDeleted = 0
)
SELECT * 
FROM TableList;
```

Comment: looks like dead end for me. Do you have any suggestion for recursive sql other than with?

Comment: @EmreErişgen: not in SQLServer.

Comment: @EmreErişgen -- you could define your Recursive CTE as a View and then use accordingly.

Comment: looks like there is no way i treat with clause as a subquery. Thank you.

Comment: the reselect of the with table in the where clause helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer of doing this in `JOIN`, so it looks like this. `WITH` statement is always the first in the sql query statement.

A `DISTINCT` keyword is applied on the `SELECT` clause in order for the result to be *unique* if ever there are records from `TestTable` that has multiple matches on the common table expression.

```
WITH TableList (tableId)
AS
(
    SELECT tableId FROM OldTable WHERE tableId=5 and IsDeleted = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.tableId From OldTable as t
    INNER JOIN TableList as p
    ON t.ParenTableId = p.TableId
    WHERE t.IsDeleted = 0
)
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    TestTable a
        INNER JOIN TableList b
            ON a.tableId = b.tableId
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

```
WITH TableList (tableId)
AS
(
    SELECT tableId FROM OldTable WHERE tableId=5 and IsDeleted = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.tableId From OldTable as t
    INNER JOIN TableList as p
    ON t.ParenTableId = p.TableId
    WHERE t.IsDeleted = 0
)
SELECT  DISTINCT t.TableId, t.IsDeleted, f.totalCount
FROM    TestTable t
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.otherTableId, COUNT(DISTINCT a.OtherId) totalCount
            FROM    OtherTable a
                    INNER JOIN TableList b
                        ON b.tableId = a.otherTableId
            GROUP   BY otherTableId
        ) f ON t.tableId = f.otherTableId
WHERE   t.tableId in (1,2,3)
```

Comment: i cant use with statement first in sql query. i need to use it like a subquery.

Comment: what is the reason why you can't use it? You cannot wrap common table expression in the subquery.